# How to stop dog from gnawing on antique posts

Tags: dogs, chewing

My young (6 months) female Shiba Inu keeps gnawing on our antique wood roof posts.

They are a few centuries old, and therefore splinter easily - which I guess is half the fun for her.

We've tried sprays for furniture but it didn't work. Neither has wrapping the posts with cling film (Saran wrap).

We are considering brushing a chili powder concoction on the posts.

Does anyone have advice?

Comment: A spray like bitter apple did not work? Since the post are porous you may need to use a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You have not had any answers so here is an idea.

Take a light packing foam.  Not the bubble stuff - a light foam.  You could even use newspaper.   Soak it in a bitter apple or chili powder or ... and wrap some legs.

Brush chili powder also seems like a good idea.

Answer (score -2):

Use plain old water in a clean spray bottle, and spritz when you catch the pup in the act.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer? How can this approach solve OP's issues?

Comment: Instead of covering the furniture, I suggest gently correcting the dog's behavior. Most dogs do not like being spritzed with water, so when you see the dog gnawing, give it a quick spritz. Eventually the dog will realize it's boundaries. If not, then you may need to consider ways to protect the furniture, but give the water spritzer a go first.